# Search File Paths Based on File Name Array

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have two string arrays in my PowerShell script:

```
$search = @('File1', 'File2');
$paths = @('C:\Foo\File1.pdf', 'C:\Foo\Bar.doc', 'C:\Foo\File2.txt');
```

How can I get all file paths which contain the file names from the search array? Can this be done in a pipeline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [GetFileNameWithoutExtension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension(v=vs.110).aspx) method to retrieve the filename of the path and use `-in` to filter them:

```
$paths | ? { [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($_) -in $search }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do partial matches you could do something like this:

```
$paths | Where-Object {
  $filename = Split-Path $_ -Leaf
  $search | Where-Object { $filename -like "*$_*" }
}
```